# Try/Except won't work with TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, timeoutexception

I am trying to see if there if the comment section is enabled on a YouTube video. if it's not, the program should return to the top again.

```
def bot1():
    while True:

        #  First search
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=CAISAggBUBQ%253D&q=" + k1)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-uix-tile-link").click()
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "comment-simplebox-renderer-collapsed-content"))
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            bot1()
```

This gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/My Programs/YouTubeTest/YouTubeTest.py", line 98, in <module>
    bot1()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/My Programs/YouTubeTest/YouTubeTest.py", line 73, in bot1
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "comment-simplebox-renderer-collapsed-content"))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I do got this

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: When do you ever expect the code to break?

Comment: After WebDriverWait. If it does not find the comment section within 10 seconds, it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, There is no condition for breaking the loop, this is an infinite loop.

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException and normal TimeoutException is different

Comment: So how do I go to the top if it doesn't find the comment section?

Comment: I dont think recursive call to bot1() is right way. Try to achieve the logic using some other ways..

Comment: Alright. But why is it giving me this error? It should work right?